# How to efficiently convert a string to a byte slice, including the final 0, in Go?

Tags: string, go, slice

I would like to convert a string to a byte slice, including the final 0 char.

I am aware that the following code converts a string to a slice :

```
my_slice := []byte("abc")
```

And that the following code can add the final 0 char:

```
my_slice = append(my_slice , 0)
```

But I wonder if it can be done more efficiently, maybe in 1 line, since both lines will allocate memory.

Inefficient example: https://play.golang.org/p/Rg6ri3H66f9

Comment: you mean like `mySlice := append([]byte("abc"), 0)`

Comment: If adding the 0 byte to you slice is the bottleneck in you application you are doing something strange. Sometimes efficiency does not matter.

Comment: What do you mean by "final 0 char"? Do you want to create a  null-terminated string, just like in c?

Comment: @mbuechmann: Yes, I want to create a null-terminated string, just like in C.

Comment: What would be the purpose of that?

Answer (score 1):

Allocate a slice of the desired length. Copy the string to the slice.

```
s := "abc"
my_slice := make([]byte, len(s)+1)
copy(my_slice, s)
```

There's no need to set the last element to zero because make returns a slice with all elements set to zero.